# Confused by Definition 14.25 in Jech regarding generic ultrafilters

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In Definition 14.25 of Jech's set theory, the canonical name $\dot{G}$ for a generic ultrafilter is the Boolean function defined by:

$$
\text{dom}(\dot{G})=\{\check{u} : u \in B \}
$$

such that:

$$
\dot{G}(\check{u}) = u \text{ for every } u \in B
$$

Here, $B$ is the a Boolean algebra for the Boolean-Valued model $V^B$, and $\check{u}$ are the elements of $\check{B}$, where $\check{B}$ is the name for $B$ in $V^B$.

My question is quite simple, but I am not sure how to answer it ... Why does the above definition suffice for $\dot{G}$ to become an ultrafilter for $\check{B}$ ? More specifically, if the definition above implies that the value of $\dot{G}(\check{u})$ is equal to $u$ for every $u \in B$, doesn't $\dot{G}$ become essentially the same as $\check{B}$ ?

i.e. what confuses me is that all $p,q \in \dot{G}$ should be compatible (since $\dot{G}$ is a filter) ... however, from the definition, the domain of $\check{G}$ is all of $B$, i.e. $\text{dom}(\dot{G})=\{\check{u} : u \in B \}$, but every $u \in B$, should also have its complement in $B$ by definition of a Boolean Algebra, but complements should be incompatible ... what am I missing ?

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ are incompatible, then they cannot both end up in $\dot G$, for example.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, what confuses me from the definition is that the domain of $\dot{G}$ is all of $B$, but from what I understand, not all elements of $B$ are compatible since for every $u \in B$, we also have its complement in $B$ ... what am I missing here ?

Comment: Although the domain of $\dot{G}$ is $B$, each condition in $B$ thinks $\dot{G}$ is different from $\check{B}$, and "the elements of $\dot{G}$" under each condition differs by the condition. For example, if $p$ and $q$ are incompatible, then $p$ forces $q\notin \dot{G}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the definition above implies that the value of $\dot{G}(\check{u})$ is equal to $u$ for every $u \in B$, doesn't $\dot{G}$ become essentially the same as $\check{B}$ ?

No, $\dot G$ does not equal to $\check B$. For example, for $u\in B$ with $u\ne 1$, $\dot G(u)=u < 1 = \check B(u)$, so they are different names.

But are they "essentially" the same? The answer is again no. In fact, if you read the following section **The Forcing Theorem and the Generic Model Theorem**, you will see that if in the base model $M$, $G$ is any generic ultrafilter on $B$, then in the generic extension $M[G]$,

1. $\dot G$ is interpreted to $G$; (although the definition of $\dot G$ does not rely on knowledge of $G$)
2. $\check B$ is interpreted to $B$;
3. $G$ is a generic ultrafilter of $B$.

> Why does the above definition suffice for $\dot{G}$ to become an ultrafilter for $\check{B}$?

Perhaps the easiest way to see this fact is this: since $$p\vDash \dot G\text{ is a generic filter of } \check B$$ for every $p\in B$, the boolean value of the above statement is $1$. It is also possible to prove this statement directly (through calculation of boolean values).

> [...]but every $u \in B$, should also have its complement in $B$ by definition of a Boolean Algebra, but complements should be incompatible ...

The statement talking about compatibility of elements in $\dot G$ is $$\|\forall p,q(p\in \dot G\wedge q\in \dot G\Rightarrow\exists r\in \dot G (r\le p\wedge r\le q))\| = 1\tag{*}$$
(Here $r\le p$ has the same boolean value of $(r,p)\in \check\le_{B}$.) In this statements, we are talking about arbitrary names $p$ and $q$, not elements of $B$. In fact, say $p=x$ and $q=(\neg x)\check{}$ are incompatible, then $$
\|p\in \dot G\wedge q\in \dot G\| = \left(\prod_{u\in B}\|p=\check u\|u\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{v\in B}\|q=\check v\|v\right)\\
\le \|p=\check x\|\cdot x\cdot\|q=(\neg x)\check{}\|\cdot\neg x=x\cdot (\neg x)=0$$
Thus these instances of $p$ and $q$ do not affect the overall boolean value in (*).

Comment: thanks, I was rushing through my readings late in the night and got so many things messed up